# Python removing a comma from last line within a for loop

Tags: python

Id like to know what it takes to remove a comma from the last line within a for loop in python. When I run the script it gives me the below output(after code section). I want to remove the comma at the end of fourth line "{"{#MACRO}":"queue4"}," Please can someone help?

By the way if there is a better way to construct the block please share the ideas. I'm a beginner and like to learn. :)

Code:

```
import json
import urllib
import string

Url= "http://guest:guest@localhost:55672/api/queues"
Response = urllib.urlopen(Url)
Data = Response.read()

def Qlist(Name):
    Text = '''    {{"{{#MACRO}}":"{Name}"}},'''.format(Name=Name)
    print Text

X_json = json.loads(Data)

print '''{
"data":['''
for i in X_json:
    VV = i['name']
    Qlist(VV)
print ''']
}'''
```

Below is the Output:

```
{
"data":[
    {"{#MACRO}":"queue1"},
    {"{#MACRO}":"queue2"},
    {"{#MACRO}":"queue3"},
    {"{#MACRO}":"queue4"},
]
}
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Never, ever, *ever* cobble together JSON by hand, or any other data serialisation format for that matter. Build a Python list/dict and `json.dumps` it!

Comment: Use join. Add formatted name to a list. Finally do ','.join(formattednamelist).

Comment: @deceze. Can you please help be presenting the json dump code. As you might have figured out I have a rabbitmq implementation with 4 queues and trying to grab their names to the given block. Mind you though the line with the key word "data":[ is a must have at the beginning of the block. Please I'm a student and it will help me a great deal if you write the code. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your loop as follows.

```
# Create and initialize a dictionary (Associative Array)
# data['data'] is an empty list.
# Variable name (data in this case) can be anything you want.
# 'data' is a key. notice the quotations around. it's not a variable.
# I used 'data' as the key, becasue you wanted your final output to include that part.
data = {"data": []}

for i in X_json:

   # We are not calling the data dictionary here.
   # We are accessing the empty list we have created inside the `data` dict (above) using data['data'] syntax.
   # We can use the append function to add an item to a list.
   # We create a new dictionary for every `name` item found in your json array and 
   #  append that new dictionary to the data['data'] list.
   data['data'].append({"{#MACRO}": i['name']})

print(json.dumps(data))
# or print json.dumps(data, indent=True)
```

Read more about `json.dumps()` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps). You can read more about python's `list` and `dictionary` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Thanks so much buddy. Your code works perfectly. As a beginner im curious to know what is being done here. The part I don't undertand is `data = {"data": []}` and inside the for loop `data['data'].append({"{#MACRO}": i['name']})`

Please would you care to explain why 'data' is called again in for loop? You've assigned "data" to a variable called data as well before the loop so cant we just call that within the loop? Thanks again buddy.

Comment: if you can modify the code with comments I think it will be easier to understand rather than replying in comments box. :)

Comment: thanks a lot man. Now it makes perfect sense. You are a genius. Any chance If you can give me your email. Or point me to a profile of yours so that I can find it myself.

Answer (score -1):

Don't `print` inside `Qlist` - instead `return` a value; then you can join all returned values using comma as separator:

```
def Qlist(Name):
    Text = '''    {{"{{#MACRO}}":"{Name}"}}'''.format(Name=Name)
    return Text

print '''{
"data":[''' +
',\n'.join([ Qlist(i['name']) for i in X_json ]) + 
''']
}'''
```

And anyway, using `json.dumps` is likely a better idea.

Comment: thanks a lot. If you can please help me out with the json.dumps code. Please read the comment I've given on deeze's reply above. thanks a lot.